# Multiple File Uploads With Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I watched http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads and tried to apply it to my project. This is what I have:

property.rb

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar, :agent_id, :address, :neighborhood, :price, :photos
  belongs_to :agent
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :large => "1500x1500>", :thumb => "100x100>" }     
  has_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

photo.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar, :property_id
  belongs_to :property
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :large => "1500x1500>"}
end
```

properties_controller.rb

```
def new
 @property = Property.new
 5.times { @property.photos.build }
end

def edit
 @property = Property.find(params[:id])
 5.times { @property.photos.build }
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Create New Listing</h1>

 <%= form_for(:property, :url => {:action => 'create'}, :html => {:multipart => true}) 
 do|f| %>

 <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
 <% f.fields_for :photo do |f| %>
 <%= f.file_field :avatar, {:multiple => true} %>
 <% end %>

<table>
<tr>
  <th>Agent_ID</th>
  <td><%= f.text_field(:agent_id) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Address</th>
  <td><%= f.text_field(:address) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Neighborhood</th>
  <td><%= f.text_field(:neighborhood) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Price</th>
  <td><%= f.text_field(:price) %></td>
</tr>
</table>

<%= submit_tag("Create Listing") %>
<%= link_to 'Return to list', 'list' %>
```

I was unable to get 5 different file fields as emerson does in his video. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code? I'm guessing that the problem is in the form page.
Any help on how to make it work is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

should:

```
<% f.fields_for :photo do |f| %>
```

not be:

```
<% f.fields_for :photos do |f| %>
```

Also I don't know if rails and paperclip support `multiple` on a file field out of the box: http://initializd.com/blog/2013/3/upload-multiple-files-with-html5-rails-mongoid-paperclip-and-google-cloud-storage